# making a function that pulls all number from an array divisible by 3

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

```
var array = [3, 4, 6, 5, 9, 10, 21];

var divThree = [];

var loveTheThrees = function (array) {
  for (i = 0; i = array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] % 3 === 0) {
      amount.push(divThree[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

I am just learning Javascript and having a bit of trouble with this function. I can feel im close but cant figure out what im doing wrong.

Comment: Note: you should write `for (var i = 0` instead of `for (i = 0`

Comment: what is your error? What state are you trying to hit now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways of going about it (as evidenced by the other answers here), but the bug in the code you posted is that the `i = array.length` is resetting the value of `i`. You'll want to use a `<` instead. You also need to push into the proper array.

```
var array = [3, 4, 6, 5, 9, 10, 21];

var divThree = [];

var loveTheThrees = function (array) {
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] % 3 === 0) {
      divThree.push(array[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation. could you further explain why `i = array.length` resets the value of `i`, and using `<` doesnt? in my head using `=` would be more appropriate, but again, im new so im not going to challenge your code!

Comment: @Josh-Harris, `=` sets a value. In your code you set it to 0, then set it again to array.length. is you want to check if something is equal to something else, you'd use `==` or `===`. Likewise, if you want to see if something is greater than or less then, you use `>` and `<` respectively. So your `for` statement as is stand says "Set `i` to 0, while set `i` to `array.length`, increment once each loop" (yes, I know that middle one reads weird. Bear with me.) If you use a `<` instead, it will read "Set `i` to 0, while `i` is less then `array.length`, increment once each loop" (cont)

Comment: (from above) The second way will loop through until `i` increments to 1 less than `array.length` (which, since arrays are 0-index means that you have looked at every item in the array), and then stop looping. I recommend you take a look at JS operators here to get a more in-depth look at how they work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators

Comment: thanks for clearing it up for me. I'll definitely look into those!

Comment: I suppose I should add why `i = array.length` works how it does. It's because that middle bit of the `for` statement is just evaluating true/false. Using a `<` will eventually return false when `i` gets too large. However, setting a variable will always return true. This is because JS says "Why yes, I did set that var. Here have a true".

Answer (score 8):

Just use filter()

```
divThree = array.filter(x => x%3 === 0);
```

Comment: To be honest i didnt even know .filter was a thing yet. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are assign `i = array.length` instead of a condition, so your loop is infinite. You need to change `=` into the `<`. And also push into the `dimThree` not to `amount`.

```js
 var array = [3, 4, 6, 5, 9, 10, 21];

    var divThree = [];
    
    var loveTheThrees = function (array) {
      for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] % 3 === 0) {
          divThree.push(array[i]);
        }
      }
    }

loveTheThrees(array);
divThree.forEach(x => console.log(x));
```

Or use `filter()` function

```js
 var array = [3, 4, 6, 5, 9, 10, 21];
    var divThree = [];
    
    divThree = array.filter(x => x % 3 === 0);

divThree.forEach(x => console.log(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.filter` of array

```
var array = [3, 4, 6, 5, 9, 10, 21];

var output = array.filter(function(num){
  return num%3 ==0
});
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

you will have to push the right value:

```
divThree.push(array[i]);
```

and: you can implement a for loop like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { .. }
```

or

```
for (var i = 0, l = array.length; i<l; i++) { .. }
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to correct the for-loop condition from `i=array.length` to `i < array.length`. But even more important in this case - you need to consider the following:
You want to add/push the values that are divisible by 3 into an array called `divThree` - so the correct syntax is `<destination-array>.push(<value-to-push>)`. So in this case, if the current value `array[i]` is divisible by three you want to push it into the array called `divThree` so you do something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] % 3 === 0) {
      //here we push array[i] into the array because it is divisible my 3
      divThree.push(array[i]);
    }
  }
```

As you progress in your Javascript, you will find that in this case, it is easier to use [lodash](https://lodash.com/) (for NodeJS apps) as it provides very nice convenience functions of these kinds of things.

I hope this helps.